# Format input value as a percent using ko.computed

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to display and make editable a stored view observable chosen from a dropdown as a percentage. Not quite sure how to obtain and reference the observable inside the read/write of the computed function. This does not work...

http://jsfiddle.net/PastorBones/zmdJb/

#### Script

```
function viewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.data = [
        {name: 'Test1', percent: ko.observable(.1)},     
        {name: 'Test2', percent: ko.observable(.543)},         
        {name: 'Test3', percent: ko.observable(.0123)}         
    ];
    self.selOption = ko.observable();
    self.chosenOptions = ko.observableArray();
    self.addData = function(){
        if(typeof(self.selOption) !== 'undefined'){
          self.chosenOptions.push(self.selOption());
          self.selOption(undefined);
        }  
    }
    self.formatAsPercent = ko.computed({
        read: function(obj){
            if(typeof(obj) === 'undefined') return '';                
            return (obj.percent() * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        },
        write: function(obj){
            var val = obj.percent().replace('%','');
            obj.percent(val / 100);            
        }
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
​
```

#### HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: data, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: selOption"></select>
<button data-bind="click: addData, enable: typeof(selOption()) !== 'undefined'">+</button>

<div data-bind="foreach: chosenOptions">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
        <input data-bind="value: $root.formatAsPercent($data)" />
    </div>
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have access to properties of the child, the computed property should be defined at *child* level.
See the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmdJb/3/

Comment: That jsFiddle link is dead.

Comment: I created a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbos/nkGSg/1/. Hope this helps you...

Comment: New fiddle is dead. Can you just include relevant code in your answer?